# Passing both scalars and arrays (of any dimensions) from Fortran to C

Tags: c, fortran, gfortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have the following Fortran subroutine named `show_value` that calls a C function named `show_value`:

```fortran
INTERFACE
    SUBROUTINE show_value(variable) BIND(C, name = "show_value")
        USE, INTRINSIC :: iso_c_binding
        TYPE(*) :: variable
    END SUBROUTINE
END INTERFACE
```

The C function `show_value`:

```
void show_value(const void *variable)
{
    printf("%d\n", *(int *) variable);
}
```

The Fortran subroutine works well when passing scalars to it. Example:

```fortran
INTEGER :: x
x = 12
call show_value(x)
```

This will call the C function `show_value` and print `12`, which is correct.

Now, according to the Fortran documentation, if one wants to enable subroutine `show_value` to receive also arrays (of any dimensions) and not just scalars, the line `TYPE(*) :: variable` should be changed to `TYPE(*), DIMENSION(..) :: variable`.

After making this change, when executing the following Fortran code:

```fortran
INTEGER, DIMENSION(3) :: y
y(1) = 15
y(2) = 17
y(3) = 19
call show_value(y)
```

The C function `show_value` no longer prints the correct message (i.e. prints random numbers). Moreover, I found out that the address that the C function receives is 528 lower than the original (in Fortran). To confirm this:

```
void show_value(const void *variable)
{
    printf("%d\n", *(int *) (variable + 528));
}
```

... which prints `15` (correct number).

Any idea what is going here?

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, gfortran 4.9

Comment: Fixed, thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your first case, with scalar argument, works correctly matching with the `void*` argument, when the argument to the call is assumed-rank (which `type(*), dimension(..) :: variable` represents) the Fortran procedure is not interoperable with the C procedure with corresponding formal argument `const void *variable`.

Instead, it is necessary to use the `CFI_cdesc_t` mechanism:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ISO_Fortran_binding.h>

void show_value(const CFI_cdesc_t* variable)
{
  printf("%d\n", *(int*) variable->base_addr);
}
```

You can find details of this in Fortran 2018 18.5.3.

Essentially, however, this is a descriptor which has much of the detail of the Fortran entity.  Here, `base_addr` is the start of the data, but you'll also find allocatable/pointer/data status, rank, extents, type.

Alas, gfortran 4.9 doesn't support this.  If it is supported at all, it will be in only very recent versions.

---

Alternatively, you may avoid using an assumed-rank assumed-type actual argument and pass instead the C-address of the argument using `c_loc`.  Not quite so elegant, but more widely supported:

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : c_loc, c_ptr, c_int
interface
  subroutine show_value(variable) bind(c)
    import c_ptr
    type(c_ptr), value :: variable
  end subroutine
end interface

integer(c_int), target :: x, y(3)

x = 12
y = [15, 17, 19]

call show_value(c_loc(x))
call show_value(c_loc(y))

end
```

This, however, leaves the problem of how the C function knows what to do with the argument.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Could you please give an example using `c_loc`? That would be great!

Comment: You do of course have the (non-portable) option of trying to understand gfortran's array descriptor which is passed (those first 528 bytes in this case).  Even if I could help there I would advise heavily against it.

Comment: Check [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Further-Interoperability-of-Fortran-with-C.html) for further information on the status of this feature in gfortran. Also, if you want to dive into the gfortran array descriptor, take look at [this](https://thinkingeek.com/2017/01/14/gfortran-array-descriptor/).